# FloatingActionButton not open dialog

Tags: android, dialog

I need help opening dialog with press float button in activity fragment.

The application does not mark any error, but pressing the floatbutton does not mark anything and does not take any action, they could help me.

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v5 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_empleado, container, false);
    return v5;
}



    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public void onClick(View v5) {

    FloatingActionButton  btndialog = (FloatingActionButton ) v5.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
    empleado = (TextView) v5.findViewById(R.id.textView2empleado);
    final String[] nivelItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nivel);
    final int itemSelected = 0;
    btndialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                    .setTitle("Selecciona el empleado")
                    .setSingleChoiceItems(nivelItems, itemSelected, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int selectedIndex) {
                            String nombreselect = "nivelItems[selectedIndex]";
                            empleado.setText(nombreselect);
                        }
                    })
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                    .show();

        }
    });

}
```

layout code:

```
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="407dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="407dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="561dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="561dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="181dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Strings.xml code:

```
<string-array name="nivel">
    <item>jornalero</item>
    <item>apuntador</item>
    <item>chofer</item>
</string-array>
```

I run the application and press the button but it does nothing, check the logcat and debug console and not show error.

Comment: Where are you calling this `onClick(View v5)` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just replace

```
public void onClick(View v5) {
```

with

```
public void onViewCreated(View viewv5, Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

`onViewCreated` is called by android after `onCreateView`. At that point your view is initialised and the click listener for your button will be set

Answer (score 2):

You have to do it like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View v5 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_empleado, container, false);
   return v5;
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View v5,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onViewCreated(v5, savedInstanceState)

   FloatingActionButton  btndialog = (FloatingActionButton ) 
               v5.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
   empleado = (TextView) v5.findViewById(R.id.textView2empleado);
   final String[] nivelItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nivel);
   final int itemSelected = 0;
   btndialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                .setTitle("Selecciona el empleado")
                .setSingleChoiceItems(nivelItems, itemSelected, new 
                DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int 
                             selectedIndex) {
                        String nombreselect = "nivelItems[selectedIndex]";
                        empleado.setText(nombreselect);
                    }
                })
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                .show();

          }
    });
}
```

Hope it works for you!